# Pandas specifying custom holidays

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to specify business days in a foreign country, but I can't get the pandas function `pd.bdate_range()` to recognize holidays. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

weekmask = "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri"

holidays = [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 9), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20),
            datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13)]

BdaysCol2017 = pd.bdate_range(start = pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1), 
                              end = pd.datetime(2017, 12, 31), 
                              weekmask = weekmask, 
                              holidays = holidays)
```

But I get the following error on the `holidays` parameter:

```
ValueError: a custom frequency string is required when holidays or weekmask are passed, got frequency B
```

Why is this? How can I specify custom holidays? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as the docs specify about weekmask and holidays:

> only used when custom frequency strings are passed

so you need:

```
BdaysCol2017 = pd.bdate_range(start = pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1), 
                          end = pd.datetime(2017, 12, 31),
                          freq='C',
                          weekmask = weekmask,
                          holidays=holidays)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that:

```
import pandas as pd  
from datetime import datetime

weekmask = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu'
exclude = [pd.datetime(2017, 3, 20),
           pd.datetime(2017, 4, 13),
           pd.datetime(2017, 5, 3)]

pd.bdate_range('2017/1/1','2017/12/31',
               freq='C',
               weekmask = weekmask,
               holidays=exclude)
```